# Is it possible to implement a key store in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Is it possible to implement a key store for external endpoints in the WSO2-Integrator?

I'm building a solution with multiple endpoints that will all have their seperate authorization keys. Currently, these are hard-coded into the sequences: the header is created right before I send the message to the endpoint. The authorization is hard-coded into that header.

Is it possible to create a seperate authorization key file and use the keys there as variables to call upon when you create the header?

**Current situation:**

```
<header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
<header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer [authorization key gibberish]"/>
   <call description="Send request to the endpoint">
      <endpoint key="PostEndpoint"/>
   </call>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `Access Tokens` should be stored securely in the server the best option is to use `securevault` and then extract the required token from Secure Vault within the integration. Once stored you can read a token like the below. Read more from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Working+with+Passwords+in+the+ESB+profile+).

```xml
<property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('accesstoken')" name="accesstoken"/>
<header name="Authorization" scope="transport" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', $ctx:accesstoken)"/>

<call description="Send request to the endpoint">
      <endpoint key="PostexEndpoint"/>
</call>
```

If you want to just store them in a properties file as key-value pairs you can refer to this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+using+Configuration+Files).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a securevault, such as [HashiCorp Vault](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/setup/security/using-hashicorp-secrets/), and call for credentials to be populated when the endpoint is [activated](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/HTTP+Endpoint).

Go down to the "Client credentials grant type" section.